# Slow File Transfer over Gigabit Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, performance, file-transfer

There are a few computers connected to a computer (Windows 7 x64) via a Gigbait network in order to transfer file, however lately the transfer of files has been really slow (11Mb/s) I have already tried adding the optimizations on the registry, however this had no effect.

Transfer of files used to be at normal speeds before. Why would this be happening?

Note: Only transfer of files through this specific computer are slow, other computers connected on the same network have normal transfer speed

Comment: Does the link speed for the network adapter show that it is full duplex 1000mb/s?

Comment: What is the duplex setting set on these slow devices set at?  Please reverse your "registry optimizations" its not required and often does more harm then good.

Comment: @RichieFrame yes I can confirm duplex at 1000mb/s

Comment: @Ramhound, the "registery optimizations" I found on this site. Still the same with our without them...

Comment: it is possible additional network filter drivers have been installed, and are filtering all network traffic between the device and winsock (internet security suites, malware, packet inspection, etc)

Comment: @rikket - Again.  Network optimization tweaks are often done by people who don't understand the actual problem. I wanted to know what duplex setting all hardware was set at.